# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' for the default code that come with the IDE

Tags: android

I am really new to the Android Studio, I actually started to teach it to myself today. When I try to run the default code

```
package omoody.funfacts;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FunFactsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fun_facts);
    }
}
```

I get the error. I am trying to run it on the emulator nexus 5 API23 Androı,id 6.0 machine. How can I fix that problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: Look for `Messages` tab in Android Studio while building project. There will be more information why your project is not building?

Comment: Try cleaning then rebuilding the project.

Comment: I tried to clean and rebuilt but still I get the same error.

Comment: in message box it says java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/dx/command/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0